# .NET Maui No Parameterless constructor defined for type (ContentView)

Tags: maui

Trying to instance a ContentView that looks like this fails with reason "No Parameterless constructor defined for type "FooView"

```
public partial class FooView : ContentView
{
    internal FooView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Parameterless constructor for FooView should have a visibility of `public`, not `internal`

Comment: I'm not sure why it was marked internal to begin with, but it was working fine before my Xamarin->Maui conversion, so maybe someone else will stumble across this same issue.